# "Else without a previous if"

Tags: c++

Hello I'm a starter programmer, please help with this one!
error "Else without a previous if"

```
cin >> input1;
if (input1 == "Story");
{
    goto Story;
}
else;
{
    if (input1 == "Creator");
    {
        goto Creator;
    }
}
goto start;
Story:
system("cls");
```

Comment: Remove all those `goto` statements. You're learning bad habits.

Answer (score 6):

Remove junk semicolons.

```
cin >> input1;
if (input1 == "Story") // remove from here
{
    goto Story;
}
else // remove from here
{
    if (input1 == "Creator") // remove from here
    {
        goto Creator;
    }
}
goto start;
Story:
system("cls");
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry!